# Fastest way to filter dataframe based on conditions multiple times

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a data frame where I need to filter on conditions multiple times (more than 200k times) to account for unique results that may come out. I am curious if there is a faster way to search and filter for particular conditions.

My current implementation is below

```
   Description Ticker     Start   Stop
0  A          B          220     100
1  Ab         TEST       180     103
2  Bac        RANDOM     205     32
3  Ba         BLAH       100     2
4  Ca         BLAH       92      40
5  Cd         B          85      25
6  A          B          221      71
7  A          B          400      171

def filter_df(object):
    stock_source = 'A'
    ticker = 'B'
    target = 120

    my_df = object.maindf[(object.maindf['Description'].values == stock_source) & (object.maindf['Ticker'].values == ticker]
    condition = (my_df['Start'].values <= target) & (my_df['Stop'].values >= target)

    my_df = my_df[condition]
    return my_df
```

For the above example I should only get rows at index 0 and 6 on which I do some other things

```
 ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
31192    1.950    0.000   37.554    0.001 test.py:95(filter_df)
```

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like:

```
stock_source = 'A'
ticker = 'B'
target = 120
m=df.Description.eq(stock_source) & df.Ticker.eq(ticker) \
            & ((df.Start.ge(target))&(df.Stop.le(target)))
df[m]

  Description Ticker  Start  Stop
0           A      B    220   100
6           A      B    221    71
```

P.S: You can create seperate boolean masks for each condition. :)

Comment: I tried that out, seems to have slowed things down.                                         31192    0.973    0.000   91.404    0.003 test.py:95(filter_df).                                One note, I need to first run the first set of conditions and filter and then run the second set. This is due to some other entries in the dataframe